# Laravel Testing login Credential using phpunit + multiprocess

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.4

I'm pretty new on unit testing and I want to try to test my login page 
my Goal for this unit are :
-> if it match in database -> redirect to route '/'
-> if not -> redirect to route '/login'

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Domain\Core\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class userTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testLoginTrue()
    {
        $credential = [
            'email' => 'user@ad.com',
            'password' => 'user'
        ];
         $this->post('login',$credential)->assertRedirect('/');
    }

    public function testLoginFalse()
    {
        $credential = [
            'email' => 'user@ad.com',
            'password' => 'usera'
        ];
        $this->post('login',$credential)->assertRedirect('/login');
    }
}
```

when I test on TestLoginTrue , its successfully return to '/' But when i try the TestLoginFalse ... it return same like TestLoginTrue, it should be stayed on '/login' route,
Any Idea?

Plus I want to try to check if when I already login I couldn't access the login page so my initial idea is :
public function testLoginTrue()

```
{
    $credential = [
        'email' => 'user@ad.com',
        'password' => 'user'
    ];
     $this->post('login',$credential)
         ->assertRedirect('/')
         ->get('/login')
         ->assertRedirect('/');
}
```

but... it returns

> 1) Tests\Feature\userTest::testLoginTrue BadMethodCallException:
>   Method [get] does not exist on Redirect.

So how to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am also a bit stuck with Laravel 5.4 testing follow redirects case.

As a workaround, you may check `$response->assertSessionHasErrors()`. This way it should work:

```
public function testLoginFalse()
{
    $credential = [
        'email' => 'user@ad.com',
        'password' => 'incorrectpass'
    ];

    $response = $this->post('login',$credential);

    $response->assertSessionHasErrors();
}
```

Also, in `testLoginTrue()` you may check, that session missing errors:

```
$response = $this->post('login',$credential);
$response->assertSessionMissing('errors');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the workaround :) , it's working perfectly . . . but I bit weird for the redirect things... the testLoginFalse return the error but not redirected accordingly to the controller.. anyway will stick with your workaround, thanks :D

Comment: Laravel 8 now comes with `$response->assertSessionHasNoErrors()`