# Laravel login test failed in phpunit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-unit-test

I am trying to do login test by phpunit in laravel. I have 5.5 so visit method is not supported. Here is what I am doing

```
public function testLoginPost(){
Session::start();

$response = $this->call('POST', 'login', [
    'email' => 'sokhter@yahoo.com',
    'password' => '123456',
    '_token' => csrf_token()
]);
$this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
$this->assertEquals('auth.login', $response->original->name());}
```

```

````
c:\wamp64\www\fundtheneedy\tests\Unit>phpunit Fundtheneedy
PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.F                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 321 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\Fundtheneedy::testLoginPost
Failed asserting that 302 matches expected 200.

C:\wamp64\www\fundtheneedy\tests\Unit\Fundtheneedy.php:30

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```
````

Comment: Surely you'll never get a 200 from the login route as it redirects on success?

Comment: Thanks! but how do I differentiate between success and fail? If both gives 302?

Answer (score 1):

If you purely look at the response code it will always be 302 which is the response code for a URL Redirect as it will redirect regardless whether or not it fails.

You can instead look at whether or not there are errors in the session which is a bit of a workaround mentioned in this post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052228/laravel-testing-login-credential-using-phpunit-multiprocess)

```
$response->assertSessionMissing('errors');
```

Or use the inverse

```
$response->assertSessionHasErrors();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you'll always be redirected, regardless of a successful or unsuccessful login, you'll have to assert the response you got.

To test a successful login, you would do:

```
$response->assertStatus(302);
$response->assertRedirect('http://your-website.com/user/dashboard');
```

To test an unsuccessful login, you would do:

```
$response->assertStatus(302);
$response->assertRedirect('http://your-website.com/auth/login');
```

That should be enough.

**PS:** Edit the urls to match whatever you have, obviously.

Comment: thanks! I am getting this. 1) Tests\Unit\Fundtheneedy::testLoginSuccess
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/seekfund'
+'http://localhost/login'

Comment: So, update it to match whatever you got. In this case, the `/login` endpoint.